# Foundation 5 slider shows two decimal points

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

```
   <div class="range-slider round" data-slider="1" data-options="display_selector: #questions_off_count; initial: 1; end: 4 ;">
          <span class="range-slider-handle" role="slider" tabindex="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="4" aria-valuenow="1" style="transform: translateX(249.5px);"></span>
          <span class="range-slider-active-segment" style="width: 25%;"></span>
          <input type="hidden" value="1">
        </div>
```

For some reason, while initialy i see the number "1" without trailing zeroes, when i move the slider i get 2 decimal zeroes after the number.

any remedy to that?

EDIT: if i use the arrows on the number input next to the slider i do not get the decimals

Comment: Do you set the step etc such that it is whole numerics only?

Comment: what i show you above in the snippet thats what there is to it haven't done anything using javascript or something if thats what you imply.

Comment: look into dataoptions a bit more.  There might be a Step function or something.

Comment: i pasted the rendered html from inspecting the document

Comment: also i copy pasted the default code snippet from foundation 5 and it stills gives me two decimals by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foundation sliders have a default precision of 2. When initializing foundation on your page, you can specify a custom precision.

For example:

```
$(document).foundation({
  slider: {
    precision: 0
  }
});
```

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/0pnb5xb4/1/)

These are the default initialization values on the latest Foundation version (v. 5.5.3):

```
settings : {
  start : 0,
  end : 100,
  step : 1,
  precision : 2,
  initial : null,
  display_selector : '',
  vertical : false,
  trigger_input_change : false,
  on_change : function () {}
}
```

Comment: finally! thank you this has been bugging me for some time! really why do they not have it documented in the range slider page???

Comment: Not sure. I always have to dig through the js files to find specific functionality. Glad it worked for you :)